# Can not get CSS style to propagate into a table cell in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

The example below works in chrome and fire fox.
Both renders the text red.
Why does IE9 fail?

Here is an example:

```
<style>
.tableX td
{
  color:red;
}
</style>


<table class='tableX'>
 <tr>
  <td>
    My Text
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it doesn't fail for me http://jsfiddle.net/e6afK/

Comment: It even works on IE9 `Browser Mode 7` and `Document Mode 7`

Comment: For some odd reason my browser had gone into a weird mode.
Must have tested too many new HTML5 features :-{
Anyways it works after restarting the browser.
Thank god i didn't spend more than three hours on it. Yikes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason my browser had gone into a weird mode. Must have tested too many new HTML5 features :-{ Anyways it works after restarting the browser. Thank god i didn't spend more than three hours on it. Yikes.
Was my initially thought.
However the problem is caching related.

To prevent IE from caching the AJAX request, i have added a variable to the querystring containing  a random number, like below:

queryString + "?comonIE=" + MATH.random().toString().slice(2)

Comment: Now i can see whats going on.
IE9 doesn't respond to changes in my HTML document that i am loading via. AJAX.
I need to restart the browser every time i change the server generated HTML that is being fetched via AJAX.
Well thats an other issue.